# how can i create react notification of get new order in react.js ,node.js ,mysql?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

I'm working on e-commerce react website.I'm facing the issue to create react order notification popup,when we recieve new order in database.please help and guide me how can i  build this functionality.i have try socket.io also.but im not able to solve it.[image: here is my dashboard image i want to update,total order no without refresh component]

Comment: what issue are you having with socket.io? because socket.io will provide real time notification and it should probably a viable solution.

Comment: unable to make socket connection with order post api response

Comment: what error are you getting can check your console, it will show the error

Comment: how can i use socket.io server inside order post rest api?

Comment: io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // ...
  console.log("working")
});

httpServer.listen(3000);

Comment: In node.js are you using express server or standard node server?

Comment: this is not showing working in console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246646/discussion-between-bhavesh-daswani-and-ashutosh-kumar).

Comment: im using,node express,mysql and sequlise orm

Comment: im not able to understand,how i can connect socket server with my node server and pass

Comment: the message  by order post api?

Answer (score 1):

With socket io you can use rooms:

Server side, on connection you let the user join the room with his userId.

```
//client side
var socket = io.connect(window.location.origin,{query:'userId=1'});
```

or better you can user a token:

```
//client side
var socket = io.connect(window.location.origin,{query:'token=YOURTOKEN'});
```

Then you can join room on connection:

```
// server side
io.socket.on('connection', function (socket) {
  let token = socket.handshake.query.token;
  userId = getUserByToken(token); // set directly userId or find your userid by token, jwt for example
  socket.join("user-"+userId);

});
```

Now, when you receive an order you need to emit the message to a specific room

```
socket.to("userID").emit("notification", "your message");
```

In you frontend you need to listen to notification:

```
socket.on("notification", (...args) => {
  // print your message
});
```

Comment: sir!! how can i make the socket.io server connection with my node.js server rest api??

Comment: ```
// socketapi.js

const io = require("socket.io")();
const socketapi = {
  io: io,
};

io.on("connection"...

```

then when you initialize your server attach the socket:
```
let socketapi = require("./socketapi");
...
var server = http.createServer(app);
socketapi.io.attach(server)

```

There are various way to attach socket, see here in the official documentation:
https://socket.io/get-started/chat#:~:text=to%20add%20it%3A-,const%20express%20%3D%20require(%27express%27)%3B%0Aconst%20app,Copy,-Notice%20that%20I

Comment: im getting this error =ReferenceError: socket is not defined

Comment: how can i create socket variable in backend order controller??

Answer (score 0):

Below is the I would approach for real-time update on the Admin dashboard when an order is placed.

- Setup Socket.IO on both Backend and Frontend
- On the frontend listen to specific channel like new-order and from the server send data of new order on new-order channel
- On the frontend when you get event for new-order show the notification to the ADMIN

Below is the implementation of the backend for Socket.io where you are facing difficulty

SocketController.ts

```
import {Server,ClientSocket} from 'socket.io';
import {Container} from "typedi";
import socketioJwt from 'socketio-jwt';

export default class SocketController {
    constructor() {

          
            .sockets
            .on('connection',socketioJwt.authorize({
                secret: Container.get('jwt_secret'),
                decodedPropertyName: 'user',
                timeout:3000,
            }))
            .on('authenticated',(socket)=>{
                socket.on('disconnect', () => {
                    delete Container.get('s-users')[socket.user.id];
                })
                Container.get('s-users')[socket.user.id] = {socketId:socket.id,userId:socket.user.id};
            })
    }
}
```

App.ts

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import express from 'express';

import SocketController from "./SocketController";


export const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


new SocketController();

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Express Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

The above is the approach you can implement Socket.io in the backend, you can skip JWT for now, as you application start working you can add JWT.

Comment: im not getting any error now in backend but why io function not printing in console?